# Oracle SQL Code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Trying to use this code, which was provided on here, however, it returns the following error when trying to run:

```
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:

    constant exception table long double ref char time timestamp interval
    date binary national character nchar

    1. DECLARE
    2. emp employee%ROWTYPE; 
    3. tbl_emp IS TABLE OF emp;
    4. v_user_type employee.user_type%TYPE;
    5. BEGIN
```

Code is:

```
DECLARE
  emp employee%ROWTYPE; 
  tbl_emp IS TABLE OF emp;
  v_user_type employee.user_type%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT user_type
  INTO v_user_type
  FROM Employee 
  WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');
  IF v_user_type = 1 
  THEN
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_emp
    FROM employee;
  ELSE
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_emp
    FROM employee;
    WHERE upper(username) = v('APP_USER');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: extra semicolon, fourth line from end.

Comment: You are missing the `TYPE` keyword on line 2 and 3, and, of course, the extra semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first declare type, then variable of that type.

E.g.

```
declare 
  type tbl_emp_type IS TABLE OF employee%ROWTYPE; 
  tbl_emp tbl_emp_type; 
begin

  select * 
  bulk collect into tbl_emp
  from employee;

end;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79edd/6)